# Problem installation of mysql instance of python

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

In **mac OSX** I have already installed `mariadb 10.1.20` now while i Try to install `mysql-python` using `pip install mysql-python` system showing following error:

```
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/eskimi/Development/ErpNext/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/1r/0z4_dp3j0237vqx1jvc0sn3c0000gp/T/pip-install-s0tXN_/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/1r/0z4_dp3j0237vqx1jvc0sn3c0000gp/T/pip-install-s0tXN_/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/1r/0z4_dp3j0237vqx1jvc0sn3c0000gp/T/pip-install-s0tXN_/mysql-python/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/1r/0z4_dp3j0237vqx1jvc0sn3c0000gp/T/pip-install-s0tXN_/mysql-python/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/1r/0z4_dp3j0237vqx1jvc0sn3c0000gp/T/pip-install-s0tXN_/mysql-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How can resolve this issue?

**N.B I am using python 2.7**

Comment: Can you try to run this before the pip install `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin` Alternative you can just run `brew install mysql`

Comment: There is no mysql directory inside local. mariadb is my requirement.

Comment: Than run the installation with `brew install mysql` afterwards run the export.

Comment: If you want to install MariaDB instead of Mysql (sorry missed that one in your question) install the MysqlConnector: `brew install mysql-connector-c`

Comment: after installing this package getting new issue.

Comment: which issue do you get. You need the mysql-connector even for maria db tough